# How to print all values of struct array in C

Tags: c, pointers

I cant seem to figure out how to set my printf statement to be able to print all elements of struct array that I'm passing to print function.

When I try to compile I get warnings:

```
format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]
```

I tried casting but still get an error.

When I run the program I just get:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Here is the code:

```
struct Card {
    char suit;
    char face;
};
int main(void)
{
   ...
   struct Card *hand[HAND_SIZE];
   dealHand(deck, face, suit, hand); //deal the deck
   printHand(hand);
}

 void dealHand(unsigned int wDeck[][FACES], const char *wFace[], const char *wSuit[], struct Card *wHand[])
{
    unsigned int c = 0;
    for (size_t card = 1; card <= HAND_SIZE; ++card) {
        for (size_t row = 0; row < SUITS; ++row) {
            for (size_t column = 0; column < FACES; ++column) {
                if (wDeck[row][column] == card){
                    struct Card aCard;
                    aCard.face = wFace[column];
                    aCard.suit = wSuit[row];
                    wHand[0] = &aCard;
                    c = c + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
void printHand(struct Card *wHand[]) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < HAND_SIZE; ++i) {
        printf("%c%c\n", wHand[i]->face, wHand[i]->suit);
    }
}
```

How can I print array of structs?

Edit: I replaced %s with %c but now getting warning:

```
incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]
                    aCard.face = wFace[column];
```

New to pointers and not sure how to go about solving this one.

Comment: Your example doesn't have enough information for someone to help you. Try to shrink your example to something that compiles and is only ~20-30 lines long. (You might find the issue yourself this way!)

Comment: And error message is quite clear. You are passing wrong type of argument.

Comment: Try to parse the warning. It actually is trying to tell you something important, and this important thing is **not** "you can get rid of me with a cast".

Comment: provide the structure of the `struct`.  try with `%c`

Comment: Do you really think that the problem is that you're trying to print *all* values of a struct in an array? Don't you think maybe the problem is simpler than that?

Comment: Error here: `aCard.face = wFace[column]` because `face` is `char` but `wFace[column]` is `char*`.

Comment: @Barmark Thanks. I tried casting to char with (char *)wFace[column] but still get an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: No, using cast in this manner will only hide compiler warnings and errors. It doesn't fix any run-time errors.

Answer (score 1):

Since suit and face of type `char`. You must use `%c` in `printf()`.

```
printf("%c%c\n", wHand[i]->face, wHand[i]->suit);
```

Comment: Mi error seems to be in dealHand function. I now get warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion] and it prints ?R instead of desired output

Comment: @user2300867 : And you have not show us `dealHand()` function. We can not simply make guess.

Comment: @user2300867 Then you should report that information in your question.